# How do I save filled out PDF form on my hard disk?

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle

I have some pdf uploaded on my website. I want my clients to fill them out on my website, and save a filled out copy to their system. The only way I have found this could be done is by clicking on print button and then save from there.

Can it possibly be done any other way. Does using Adobe LiveCycle could help?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: With the right headers, you can force a download of the PDF. When they then open it, they open in in Adobe Reader, which I think will let you save filled out forms in a normal way.

Comment: Right now its embedded in iframe ... how do you recommend we do it ...

Comment: XFA (created using LiveCycle Designer) would not help anything; it would, however, make things more complicated, as you would have to assign Extended Rights to the form, so that the user can save it locally, if using Adobe Reader.

Comment: What happens if you add a button with a Save as… Action? It should work even in the browser.

Comment: How am I going to add a save as button to the pdf?